# Selected Spinner array into TextView

Tags: java, android

I have my spinner pulling from an array,(that works)..
What I want to happen is I have several textviews that will map to whatever is selected from the spinner array... e.g British Columbia. then the Texviews will all say british columbia.
I figure i should be using a setText of some kind but have been on able to find an example anyhelp would be appreciated.
Here is my spinner code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);    
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(            
            this, R.array.material_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);    
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    final TextView tv34=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv34); 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View view, int pos, long id) { 
        tv34.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()); 
        } 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { 
        // Do nothing. 
        }        
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final String[] array=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.material_array);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {

        mTextView_1.setText(array[position]);
        mTextView_2.setText(array[position]);
        mTextView_3.setText(array[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                
    }
});
```

**EDIT :**

Or you can do it like:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {

        String selectedItem=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        mTextView_1.setText(selectedItem);
        mTextView_2.setText(selectedItem);
        mTextView_3.setText(selectedItem);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples, but it looks like these are using a String array not the array adapter? Any ideas on what i need to change for this..

Comment: You don't need to change your code for the adapter.Neither it uses String array only.You have to save your array to a local array object just to match the object as per the position selected into the spinner and set the same text to textView.